# Cannot plot stacked parlot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

I have a data frame where column 1 represents bacteria names and the rest of the columns are samples. I would like to plot a stacked barplot illustrating the bacterial community composition of each sample.

This is what my data frame looks like (ignore extremely small percentages, I have sorted bacteria names alphabetically and yes, the sum of each column adds up to 100%):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YR7N.png)

I have tried:

```
# Create a list of sample file names
samples = grouped_sorted_df.columns[1:]

# Create a stacked bar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.bar(grouped_sorted_df['#Classification'], grouped_sorted_df[samples[0]], label=samples[0])
for i in range(1, len(samples)):
    ax.bar(grouped_sorted_df['#Classification'], grouped_sorted_df[samples[i]], bottom=grouped_sorted_df[samples[:i]].sum(axis=1), label=samples[i])

# Set the x-axis and y-axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('#Classification')
ax.set_ylabel('Abundance')
ax.set_title('Abundance of Bacteria genuses in Sample Files')
ax.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

but this produces an extremely horrible graph that is not even close to a stacked barplot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFb9J.png)
example of the dataset (comma used as delimiter)

```
#Classification,S25.tabular,S26.tabular,S27.tabular,S37.tabular
A2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
AKYG587,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
ASF356,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
Acetitomaculum,0.003170610553905664,0.0007126364698839827,0.002212144674261697,0.0046487254040164985
Acidibacter,0.004227480738540885,0.0007126364698839827,0.0011060723371308485,0.0025356684021908176
Acidipila,0.0010568701846352213,0.0,0.0,0.0
Actinomyces,0.5717667698876547,0.12756192810923292,0.3815949563101427,20.320846575157212
Actinomycetospora,0.0021137403692704426,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
Actinoplanes,0.0010568701846352213,0.0,0.0,0.0
Actinotignum,0.0,0.0,0.0011060723371308485,0.0
Aeromicrobium,0.0021137403692704426,0.0,0.0,0.0
Aggregatibacter,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0012678342010954088
Ahniella,0.0,0.0,0.002212144674261697,0.0
Akkermansia,0.0010568701846352213,0.0014252729397679655,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
Alcanivorax,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
Alloprevotella,0.32445914668301296,0.005701091759071862,0.8649485676363234,3.8626681993373455
Altererythrobacter,0.006341221107811328,0.0,0.0011060723371308485,0.00042261140036513626
Amycolatopsis,0.0010568701846352213,0.0,0.0011060723371308485,0.00042261140036513626
Anaerococcus,0.0010568701846352213,0.0014252729397679655,0.0,0.0
Anaerofustis,0.0,0.0007126364698839827,0.0,0.0
Anaeroglobus,0.013739312400257877,0.0,0.0,0.43528974237609036
Anaeroplasma,0.04121793720077363,0.0206664576266355,0.025439663754009516,0.027469741023733858
Anaerotruncus,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
Anaerovibrio,0.00845496147708177,0.0049884552891878795,0.005530361685654242,0.0038035026032862264
Anaerovorax,0.006341221107811328,0.007126364698839828,0.003318217011392545,0.00887483940766786
Aquicella,0.004227480738540885,0.0,0.0,0.00042261140036513626
Arenimonas,0.0,0.0,0.002212144674261697,0.0
Atopobium,2.7827391961445374,0.6292580029075568,1.9168233602477602,0.7053384272094124
Bdellovibrio,0.00951183166171699,0.0,0.005530361685654242,0.0038035026032862264
```

Comment: Well, you have too many x-values. 265 names won't fit nicely next to each other.  265 bars need to be rather thin. Maybe you could filter the dataframe to only show those x-values for which the sum of the y-values is larger than some cut-off?  To rotate the x tick labels, you can use `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)`

Comment: the issue is that I need those values to be on Y axis and x axis to show sample files (1 per column, 4 in total)

Comment: The easiest way to plot your stacked bars is via `grouped_sorted_df.set_index ('#Classification').plot.bar(stacked=True)`, but that won't solve the problem of you not reducing the number of bacteria to include in the plot.  You can also switch the bacteria and the samples, transposing the dataframe: `grouped_sorted_df.set_index ('#Classification').T.plot.bar(stacked=True)`, with only 4 stacks each with 265 bacteria and a very horrible legend.

Answer (score 0):

You can set size with [matplotlib setp width](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) once pandas plotiing is done like so

```
for i in ax.containers:
    plt.setp(i, width=1) #Change width here 
plt.tight_layout()
```

To fix the x axis ticks simply tune frequency of ticks

```
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::4]) #Plug frequncy numbers here until graphs looks good
```

In your code

```
# Create a list of sample file names
samples = grouped_sorted_df.columns[1:]

# Create a stacked bar plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.bar(grouped_sorted_df['#Classification'], grouped_sorted_df[samples[0]], label=samples[0])
for i in range(1, len(samples)):
    ax.bar(grouped_sorted_df['#Classification'], grouped_sorted_df[samples[i]], bottom=grouped_sorted_df[samples[:i]].sum(axis=1), label=samples[i])

# Set the x-axis and y-axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('#Classification')
ax.set_ylabel('Abundance')
ax.set_title('Abundance of Bacteria genuses in Sample Files')
ax.legend()
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::4]) #Plug numbers here

for i in ax.containers:
    plt.setp(i, width=1) #Change width here 


# Show the plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply! Unfortunately, this addition does not fix anything.

Comment: Change numbers in both cases .... Compare results `[::4])` with ---> some other bigger number and similarly width too. If u want exact solution post data

Comment: Thank you so much! stackoverflow does not allow me to upload the whole CSV file, so I have edited the post with example dataset